# php explode / split - co-existence in single script

Tags: php, split, explode

I have php two servers with different versions of php,
and am having trouble with split statement which seems to be deprecated on new box.
I replaced with explode which is not known to old box.

```
$connect = explode(";", DB_CONNECT);

$connect =  split(";", DB_CONNECT);
```

what statement(s) will make both servers happy?
Upgrading is not an option tonight.

Comment: What version of PHP is the server running that doesn't recognize explode?  Explode has been available in PHP for over 10 years.

Comment: What does DB_CONNECT contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better option in the short term is to disable the warning until you're able to upgrade your PHP version.

- See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 1):

If explode doesnt exist, create it

```
if (!function_exists('explode')) { 
   function explode($str, $array) {
      return split($str, $array); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) and [`preg_match_all()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php). The latter doesn't return an array, but may fill in an array pass in as third argument.

Comment: well, if explode doesn't exist, that's hopeful.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this but hopefully it will work. Good luck.

```
function ultraExplode($del,$arr){
$ver=phpversion();
if ($ver>=5) return explode($del,$arr);
else return split($del,$arr);}
```